# Help needed with making a program that calculates moving average

Tags: c

I need to calculate average with the size of span and which is moving by one element and outputting the average of elements till the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

void moving_average (int size, double a[], int span) 
{  
    int k;  
    double sum;  
    int n;  
    int count;  
    double output;  
    n=size-span;  
    for(count=0;count <= n;count++)  
    {  
        for(k=count; k<(count+span); k++)  
        sum+=a[k];  
        output=sum/span;  
        printf("%lf", output);  
    }  
}  

int main(void)  
{  
    double array[]={10,9,15,6,7};  
    moving_average(5,array[], 2);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: I find it odd the title of your question has more details than the body. Also what exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the warning level of your compiler!

There's a syntax error in the call to `moving_average()` which your compiler should have caught.

And `sum` is not initialized which your compiler should warn you about if it is properly setup.

Comment: @Cfinal it would be polite to check one of the answers "accepted" after the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the brackets after `array` in the call to `moving_average`
- Set `sum = 0` before `for(k=count; k<(count+span); k++)`
- add a `\n` in your printf